# SSL Error with tornado HTTPClient

Tags: python, ssl, tornado

I'm trying to use tornado's http client to fetch a URL. I've done this before many times, but I'm getting a really odd SSL error this time. The endpoint I'm trying to consume does not have a valid cert, but a -k on a curl call still proves it works.

```
$ curl https://myhostname.com:9001
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

$ curl https://myhostname.com:9001 -k
404 page not found
```

All of the answers I've found online just recommend setting validate_cert to False (which I'm already doing). But when I try to do what I think is the equivalent in tornado's httpclient (validate_cert=False), I still get a really odd error. Here is a test piece of code that breaks:

```
import tornado.httpclient

request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(
    url="https://myhostname.com:9001",
    method="GET",
    validate_cert=False
)
print tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient().fetch(request)
```

Here is the result:

```
WARNING:tornado.general:SSL Error on 6 ('myhostname.com', 9001): [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    make_call()
  File "/Users/kaleb.pomeroy/workspace/lefty/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 140, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./test.py", line 13, in make_call
    response = tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient().fetch(request)
  File "/Users/kaleb.pomeroy/workspace/lefty/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/httpclient.py", line 85, in fetch
    self._async_client.fetch, request, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/kaleb.pomeroy/workspace/lefty/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/ioloop.py", line 370, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "/Users/kaleb.pomeroy/workspace/lefty/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/concurrent.py", line 65, in result
    raise self._exception
tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Unfortunately my endpoint is not public, so I can't provide the exact code that I'm using to generate this error.

Has anyone seen this error, or have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might be related to the logic at https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/fd4d8997a772829b8439322dbce45091bc51beaf/tornado/simple_httpclient.py#L196
It's a known issue that `tornado.simple_httpclient` has trouble connecting to certain servers on Python 2.6, and this looks like the same error message, but I haven't seen this failure on Python 2.7 before.

Try passing `ssl_options={"ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1}` to the HTTP request.  You can also try `tornado.curl_httpclient` for an alternate implementation which is more likely to handle less-common server configurations.